# Android LayoutInflator - Multiple views in for loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating my first app with Java for android in android studio and have some problems with the LayoutInflator.

The java code of the Activity looks like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MatchActivity extends MatchSettingsActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {

    public ArrayList<Player> matchParticipants = new ArrayList<>();
    public String matchType;
    public int setsAmount;
    public int legsAmount;
    public String checkOutType;
    public String atcMode;
    public int matchFinished;
    public final String matchType501 = "501";
    public final String matchType301 = "301";
    public ArrayList<View> playerRowViewsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match);
        ImageButton backButton = findViewById(R.id.match_back_button);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Match match = (Match) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("match_object");

        setMatchSettings(match.matchParticipants, match.matchType,
                Integer.parseInt(match.setsAmount), Integer.parseInt(match.legsAmount),
                match.checkOut, match.atcMode, match.matchFinished);

        createMatchUI(matchType, matchParticipants);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.match_back_button) {
            Intent matchIntent = new Intent(MatchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            MatchActivity.this.startActivity(matchIntent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }

    public void createMatchUI(String matchType, ArrayList<Player> matchParticipants) {

        LinearLayout mainMatchLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_match_layout);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        if (matchType.equals(matchType501) || matchType.equals(matchType301)) {
            for (int i=0; i<matchParticipants.size(); i+=1) {

                View playerRowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_row_layout, mainMatchLayout, false);
                TextView nameTextView = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView pointsTextView = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.points);
                TextView averageTextView = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.average);
                TextView lastDart1 = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.last_d1);
                TextView lastDart2 = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.last_d2);
                TextView lastDart3 = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.last_d3);
                TextView lastDartsCombined = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.last_darts_combined);

                nameTextView.setText(matchParticipants.get(i).playerName);
                if (matchType.equals(matchType501)) {
                    pointsTextView.setText(matchType501);
                } else {
                    pointsTextView.setText(matchType301);
                }
                averageTextView.setText("");
                lastDart1.setText("");
                lastDart2.setText("");
                lastDart3.setText("");
                lastDartsCombined.setText("");

                playerRowViewsArrayList.add(playerRowView);
            }

            for (int i1=0; i1<playerRowViewsArrayList.size(); i1+=1) {
                mainMatchLayout.addView(playerRowViewsArrayList.get(i1));
            }
        }
    }

    public void setMatchSettings(ArrayList<Player> matchParticipants, String matchType,
                                 int setsAmount, int legsAmount, String checkOutType,
                                 String atcMode, int matchFinished) {

        this.matchParticipants = matchParticipants;
        this.matchType = matchType;
        this.setsAmount = setsAmount;
        this.legsAmount = legsAmount;
        this.checkOutType = checkOutType;
        this.atcMode = atcMode;
        this.matchFinished = matchFinished;
    }
}
```

In the method createMatchUI I am trying to display one view for each player Object in a list.

The layout that should be created for each player using the LayoutInflator looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/last_d1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/last_darts_combined"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_d1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/last_d2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/points"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/last_darts_combined"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_d2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/last_d3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_d1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/points"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_d3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sets"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_d2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/points"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_darts_combined"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/last_d3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/last_d1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sets"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/legs"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_d3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/points"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/legs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sets"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/points"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_darts_combined"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rl_button_blue_borderless"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/points"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/last_d1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/points"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/last_d2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_d1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider4"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/last_d3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_d2"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider5"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sets"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_d3"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider6"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/legs"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sets"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider7"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/legs"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/points"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/points"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/points"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the root activity/layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/match_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
        android:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/match_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/match_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/match_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/match_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/match_toolbar"
        android:text="@string/match_label"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suit_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/match_back_button"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_arrow2"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/match_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/match_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/match_toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_match_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/match_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/input_layout"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        [...]
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem I am facing is, that always only one view is added to the root layout (mainMatchLayout) like this:

[image: example]

Instead I want one layout for each player object that exists in my ArrayList matchParticipants.

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess the problem is `main_match_layout` has horizontal orientation . I would suggest better use a `RecyclerView` .

Comment: How could I not see that? I thought I checked that, but apparently I didn't. Changing the orientation to vertical solved the problem. Whats the advantage of using a `RecyclerView` instead of a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Everything is advantage can't list them all here. `RecyclerView` is the widget build for showing list data..